# Lua import library from local path (luasocket)

Tags: lua, luasocket

I'm quite new to Lua and I have some problems with the import mechanism.
From other languages I'm used to do something like this:

```
include "./lib/mylib.h"
```

or in general just to pass the local path to the file I would like to include.

Now in Lua it is a bit confusing to me. I read something about that `require` looks for the library in the lua path.
In my case I would like to create a script that uses the luasocket library but I would like to import it from a local path so that I can deploy it without the need to have it on another machine in the lua path.

From other forums I got solutions like creating a `local` require function that looks in a given local library folder but that didn't work.

Then I read that I can just type `require 'myfile'` to import a different file locally but luasocket requires a core.dll and if I just move the lua files of the library to my local path it can't find the dll.

Is there an easy way to solve this. What do I have to do to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient for the .dll extension to be in the `LUA_CPATH` (so it ends up in `package.cpath`). For example, put the `socket.lua` in `C:\Foo`, and put `core.dll` in same folder. Then `require 'socket'` will fail:

```
> print(package.cpath)
.\?.dll;.\?51.dll;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\?.dll;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\?51.dl
l;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\clibs\?.dll;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\clibs\?51.dll;C:
\Program Files\Lua\5.1\loadall.dll;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\clibs\loadall.dll
> print(package.path)
;.\?.lua;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\?.lua;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\?\init.
lua;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\?.lua;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\?\init.lua;C:\Progra
m Files\Lua\5.1\lua\?.luac
> require 'socket'
.\socket.lua:13: module 'socket.core' not found:
        -- look for preload
        no field package.preload['socket.core']
        -- look for .lua in socket folder anywhere on package.path:
        no file '.\socket\core.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\socket\core.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\socket\core\init.lua'
        ...
        -- look for .luac in socket folder anywhere on package.path:
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\socket\core.luac'
        -- look for .dll in socket folder anywhere on package.cpath:
        no file '.\socket\core.dll'
        no file '.\socket\core51.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\socket\core.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\socket\core51.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\clibs\socket\core.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\clibs\socket\core51.dll'
        ...
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        .\socket.lua:13: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

because `socket.lua` requires `socket.core`, so Lua interpreter looks for `core.lua` in a "socket" folder anywhere on `package.path`, doesn't find it (socket folder doesnt' exist), then looks for `core.dll` in `socket` folder anywhere on `package.cpath`, same problem.

Now create `C:\Foo\socket` folder, and move `core.dll` to it, then `require 'socket'` will work (from interpreter started while cd to `C:\Foo`).

In your case, if you have `yourLuaScript.lua` in `C:\Foo`, you could have `socket.lua` in same folder, `core.dll` in `C:\Foo\socket`, and `yourLuaScript.lua` could `require 'socket'` and, as long as `package.path` contains `.\*.lua`, and `package.cpath` contains `.\*.dll`, you will be able to run `yourLuaScript.lua`.

Comment: I am using ubuntu so there is no file `core.lua`